# Remove the horizontal space between 2 divs.Margin is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a div(.videos1) which includes 2 divs(.test and .test1).I want to remove the space between this 2 divs using margin-left/right:0px;but it's not working,maybe because of floats.I need 2 divs in the center with some space.[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="videos1">

<div class="test"><img src="img1.jpg"></div><div class="test1"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.videos1{
    text-align: center; 
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;

}

.test{   

 float:left;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;



}

.test1{
 float:right; /* I used float:left,but it's not my wanted result */
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox can do this.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
}
.box1, .box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
.box2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```